# Getting the user's google identity from a chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, google-identity

I thought I had things rolling but I've discovered I have this error after calling getAuthToken with interactive:false :

> OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'Bad Request'

'Bad Request' really tells me very little. Ok, I understand I'll probably need to use interative:true (why?) and so when I attempt that, it spawns my browser, prompts my google login (which I enter and which is a real pain because we have 2-step authentication), then does... nothing... the callback is never called...

Anyone interested in helping me out will probably want to see bits from my manifest.json:

```js
"key": "MII...QAB",
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "35...-lnf...1pd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [ "identity" ]
},
"permissions":[ "identity", "https://accounts.google.com/*", "https://www.googleapis.com/*", "https://*.amazonaws.com/*", "<all_urls>" ],
```

You'll also probably want to see the code in question:

```js
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true, 'scopes':['identity'] }, function ( token ) {
    if ( chrome.runtime.lastError ) {
        next(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
        next( null, token );
    }
});
```

or, alternatively:

```js
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': false }, function ( token ) {
    if ( chrome.runtime.lastError ) {
        next(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
        next( null, token );
    }
});
```

I am happy to provide any other information that might be helpful in identifying where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It's meant to be used with the browser's already signed in chrome session (the one signed in on chrome://settings) and if you're already signed in there, it will allow single-click authorization.

Comment: @kzahel : yes, i understand that part. it does prompt me to sign in (although I'm already signed in)... then it does nothing and the callback (with token) is never called unless i set interactive:false ... then it tells me "Bad Request" (not enough information to go on...)

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getAuthToken) the purpose/meaning of boolean value in the interactive object, Fetching a token may require the user to sign-in to Chrome, or approve the application's requested scopes. If the `interactive` flag is `true`, `getAuthToken` will prompt the user as necessary. When the flag is `false` or omitted, `getAuthToken` will return failure any time a prompt would be required.

Now for your error `OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'Bad Request'`

Make sure you provide the Email Address and Product Name in the Consent screen in creating OAuth credentials.

For more information, check this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/HMe3mqCRObc).